# How do I use a noindex hint in the outermost query of a nested query?

Tags: sql, oracle, hints

I have a query structure where I've got 3 nested queries (e.g. select * from (select * from (select * from table ) a ) b

There's an index in trying to avoid,  because it was causing long run times. It appeared twice in the plan. I used a noindex hint on the innermost query to remove one instance of it, but I can't seem to get rid of the second instance.

Is there a way to use noindex on the outer queries of a nested query?

Edit: More detailed query example. Note, in the real query there are GROUP BY statements on every level, but a WHERE statement only in the innermost query.

```
Select /*+ parallel(8) no_index(b,bad_index)  */
 b.col1
 b.col2
 b.col3 
FROM
  (Select /*+ parallel(8) no_index(a,bad_index)  */
    a.col1
    a.col2
    a.col3
  FROM 
(SELECT  /*+ parallel(8) no_index(t,bad_index)  */
       t.col1
       t.col2
       t.col3
    
    FROM table_1 t
    INNER JOIN table_2 t2
          ON t.col1=t2.col1
    WHERE
        t.col2='value' ) a
) b
```

Plan is below. Note, this is the actual execution plan that I changed the names  of the tables for anonymity. There are joins I didn't include in the example for simplicity's sake. Lines 72/73 include the index that I'm trying to avoid.  I added the predicate information.

```
   | Id   | Operation                                                                       | Name                      | Rows      | Bytes       | Cost    | Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                                                |                           |  84613730 | 20138067740 | 5534656 | 00:03:37 |
|    1 |   PX COORDINATOR                                                                |                           |           |             |         |          |
|    2 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)                                                          | :TQ10014                  |  84613730 | 20138067740 | 5534656 | 00:03:37 |
|    3 |     SORT GROUP BY                                                               |                           |  84613730 | 20138067740 | 5534656 | 00:03:37 |
|    4 |      PX RECEIVE                                                                 |                           |  84613730 | 20138067740 | 5534656 | 00:03:37 |
|    5 |       PX SEND HASH                                                              | :TQ10013                  |  84613730 | 20138067740 | 5534656 | 00:03:37 |
|    6 |        SORT GROUP BY                                                            |                           |  84613730 | 20138067740 | 5534656 | 00:03:37 |
|    7 |         PX RECEIVE                                                              |                           |  84613730 | 20138067740 | 5534656 | 00:03:37 |
|    8 |          PX SEND HASH                                                           | :TQ10012                  |  84613730 | 20138067740 | 5534656 | 00:03:37 |
|    9 |           SORT GROUP BY                                                         |                           |  84613730 | 20138067740 | 5534656 | 00:03:37 |
|   10 |            VIEW                                                                 |                           |  84613730 | 20138067740 | 5135062 | 00:03:21 |
|   11 |             WINDOW SORT                                                         |                           |  84613730 | 22338024720 | 5135062 | 00:03:21 |
|   12 |              PX RECEIVE                                                         |                           |  84613730 | 22338024720 | 5135062 | 00:03:21 |
|   13 |               PX SEND HASH                                                      | :TQ10011                  |  84613730 | 22338024720 | 5135062 | 00:03:21 |
|   14 |                WINDOW BUFFER                                                    |                           |  84613730 | 22338024720 | 5135062 | 00:03:21 |
|   15 |                 SORT GROUP BY                                                   |                           |  84613730 | 22338024720 | 5135062 | 00:03:21 |
|   16 |                  PX RECEIVE                                                     |                           |  84613730 | 22338024720 | 5135062 | 00:03:21 |
|   17 |                   PX SEND HASH                                                  | :TQ10010                  |  84613730 | 22338024720 | 5135062 | 00:03:21 |
|   18 |                    HASH GROUP BY                                                |                           |  84613730 | 22338024720 | 5135062 | 00:03:21 |
|   19 |                     VIEW                                                        |                           |  84613730 | 22338024720 | 4201665 | 00:02:45 |
|   20 |                      WINDOW SORT                                                |                           |  84613730 | 33760878270 | 4201665 | 00:02:45 |
|   21 |                       PX RECEIVE                                                |                           |  84613730 | 33760878270 | 4201665 | 00:02:45 |
|   22 |                        PX SEND HASH                                             | :TQ10009                  |  84613730 | 33760878270 | 4201665 | 00:02:45 |
|   23 |                         WINDOW BUFFER                                           |                           |  84613730 | 33760878270 | 4201665 | 00:02:45 |
|   24 |                          SORT GROUP BY                                          |                           |  84613730 | 33760878270 | 4201665 | 00:02:45 |
|   25 |                           PX RECEIVE                                            |                           |  84613730 | 33760878270 | 4201665 | 00:02:45 |
|   26 |                            PX SEND HASH                                         | :TQ10008                  |  84613730 | 33760878270 | 4201665 | 00:02:45 |
|   27 |                             HASH GROUP BY                                       |                           |  84613730 | 33760878270 | 4201665 | 00:02:45 |
| * 28 |                              HASH JOIN                                          |                           |  84613730 | 33760878270 | 2809746 | 00:01:50 |
|   29 |                               PX RECEIVE                                        |                           |     48812 |     1366736 |       2 | 00:00:01 |
|   30 |                                PX SEND BROADCAST                                | :TQ10003                  |     48812 |     1366736 |       2 | 00:00:01 |
|   31 |                                 PX BLOCK ITERATOR                               |                           |     48812 |     1366736 |       2 | 00:00:01 |
|   32 |                                  TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                      | Table5       |     48812 |     1366736 |       2 | 00:00:01 |
| * 33 |                               HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                             |                           |  84350244 | 31293940524 | 2809707 | 00:01:50 |
|   34 |                                PX RECEIVE                                       |                           |     48812 |     1025052 |       2 | 00:00:01 |
|   35 |                                 PX SEND BROADCAST                               | :TQ10004                  |     48812 |     1025052 |       2 | 00:00:01 |
|   36 |                                  PX BLOCK ITERATOR                              |                           |     48812 |     1025052 |       2 | 00:00:01 |
|   37 |                                   TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                     | Table5       |     48812 |     1025052 |       2 | 00:00:01 |
| * 38 |                                HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                            |                           |  84087578 | 29430652300 | 2809669 | 00:01:50 |
|   39 |                                 PX RECEIVE                                      |                           |     37177 |      669186 |       3 | 00:00:01 |
|   40 |                                  PX SEND BROADCAST                              | :TQ10005                  |     37177 |      669186 |       3 | 00:00:01 |
|   41 |                                   PX BLOCK ITERATOR                             |                           |     37177 |      669186 |       3 | 00:00:01 |
|   42 |                                    TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                    | Table4              |     37177 |      669186 |       3 | 00:00:01 |
| * 43 |                                 HASH JOIN                                       |                           |  84087578 | 27917075896 | 2809629 | 00:01:50 |
|   44 |                                  TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                      | Table4                |     37177 |      669186 |       3 | 00:00:01 |
| * 45 |                                  HASH JOIN OUTER                                |                           |  84087578 | 26403499492 | 2809590 | 00:01:50 |
|   46 |                                   JOIN FILTER CREATE                            | :BF0000                   |  84087578 | 17490216224 | 2134146 | 00:01:24 |
|   47 |                                    PX RECEIVE                                   |                           |  84087578 | 17490216224 | 2134146 | 00:01:24 |
|   48 |                                     PX SEND HASH (NULL RANDOM)                  | :TQ10006                  |  84087578 | 17490216224 | 2134146 | 00:01:24 |
| * 49 |                                      HASH JOIN BUFFERED                         |                           |  84087578 | 17490216224 | 2134146 | 00:01:24 |
|   50 |                                       PART JOIN FILTER CREATE                   | :BF0001                   | 345508495 | 11401780335 |  589579 | 00:00:24 |
|   51 |                                        PX RECEIVE                               |                           | 345508495 | 11401780335 |  589579 | 00:00:24 |
|   52 |                                         PX SEND HASH                            | :TQ10000                  | 345508495 | 11401780335 |  589579 | 00:00:24 |
|   53 |                                          PX PARTITION LIST INLIST               |                           | 345508495 | 11401780335 |  589579 | 00:00:24 |
| * 54 |                                           TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL             | Table3 | 345508495 | 11401780335 |  589579 | 00:00:24 |
| * 55 |                                       HASH JOIN                                 |                           |  84087578 | 14715326150 | 1532914 | 00:01:00 |
|   56 |                                        JOIN FILTER CREATE                       | :BF0003                   |  84087578 | 12276786388 | 1201043 | 00:00:47 |
|   57 |                                         PART JOIN FILTER CREATE                 | :BF0002                   |  84087578 | 12276786388 | 1201043 | 00:00:47 |
|   58 |                                          PX RECEIVE                             |                           |  84087578 | 12276786388 | 1201043 | 00:00:47 |
|   59 |                                           PX SEND HASH                          | :TQ10001                  |  84087578 | 12276786388 | 1201043 | 00:00:47 |
|   60 |                                            PX PARTITION LIST INLIST             |                           |  84087578 | 12276786388 | 1201043 | 00:00:47 |
| * 61 |                                             TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL           | Table1      |  84087578 | 12276786388 | 1201043 | 00:00:47 |
|   62 |                                        PX RECEIVE                               |                           | 388151817 | 11256402693 |  320877 | 00:00:13 |
|   63 |                                         PX SEND HASH                            | :TQ10002                  | 388151817 | 11256402693 |  320877 | 00:00:13 |
|   64 |                                          JOIN FILTER USE                        | :BF0003                   | 388151817 | 11256402693 |  320877 | 00:00:13 |
|   65 |                                           PX PARTITION LIST INLIST              |                           | 388151817 | 11256402693 |  320877 | 00:00:13 |
| * 66 |                                            TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL            |Table2           | 388151817 | 11256402693 |  320877 | 00:00:13 |
|   67 |                                   PX RECEIVE                                    |                           | 191371730 | 20285403380 |  660306 | 00:00:26 |
|   68 |                                    PX SEND HASH                                 | :TQ10007                  | 191371730 | 20285403380 |  660306 | 00:00:26 |
|   69 |                                     JOIN FILTER USE                             | :BF0000                   | 191371730 | 20285403380 |  660306 | 00:00:26 |
|   70 |                                      PX PARTITION LIST INLIST                   |                           | 191371730 | 20285403380 |  660306 | 00:00:26 |
| * 71 |                                       TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED | Table1      | 191371730 | 20285403380 |  660306 | 00:00:26 |
|   72 |                                        BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS              |                           |           |             |         |          |
| * 73 |                                         BITMAP INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | BAD_INDEX     |           |             |         |          |



   * 73 - access("B"."date_field"(+)>=TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE@!-INTERVAL'+00-06' YEAR(2) TO MONTH),'YYYYMMDD')))
* 73 - filter(NVL("B"."date_field"(+),99990101)>=TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE@!-INTERVAL'+00-06' YEAR(2) TO MONTH),'YYYYMMDD')) AND
  "B"."date_field"(+)>=TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE@!-INTERVAL'+00-06' YEAR(2) TO MONTH),'YYYYMMDD')))
```

Comment: You example is probably *oversimplified* as you access only one table without a `where` condition. You'll have to post a more realistic example along with the resulting *execution plan*.

Comment: I have edited the post to include more information.

Comment: Pls post also predicate information, at least for the lines  71 + 73

Comment: Added, and that actually showed me where the problem was. The same table is joined a second time with a different alias, and it was getting the bad index from that. Fee free to use as your answer, since you led me down the right path.

Comment: @cad what's your oracle version? It's important for more detailed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to look into [the extended syntax of the `no_index` hint](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-0CE4D80E-76A5-4082-A2D1-5FB7D7F67366):

[image]

```
no_index( [queryblock] tablespec [indexspec])
```

where [`tablespec`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-D316D545-89E2-4D54-977F-FC97815CD62E) is
[image: tablespec]

So for example for this query:

```sql
Select
 b.col1,
 b.col2,
 b.col3 
FROM
  (Select
    a.col1,
    a.col2,
    a.col3
  FROM 
   (SELECT
       t.col1,
       t.col2,
       t.col3
    FROM table_1 t
    JOIN table_2 t2
         on t.col1 = t2.col1
    WHERE
        t2.col2=:bind
   ) a
) b;
```

You can use `no_index(b.a.t2)`, ie outer inline view b, then inner inline view a, and finally your table alias.
BUT(!) don't forget about official [note](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-D316D545-89E2-4D54-977F-FC97815CD62E):

> **Note**: Specifying a global hint using the tablespec clause does not work for queries that use **ANSI** joins, because the optimizer generates additional views during parsing. Instead, specify @queryblock to indicate the query block to which the hint applies.

So for ANSI joins (queries with `join`), it's better to use `@queryblock`. And it's easier to use explain plan additional sections like `alias, projection, note, report_hint`. You can do it easily with `format=>'all'`, but I would suggest also `+outline` and `+hint_report`, for example:

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format=>'all +outline +hint_report'));
```

From the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_XPLAN.html#GUID-2E479BE4-FEEA-400E-A218-DC779A2181CF):

> **format**
> Controls the level of details for the plan. It accepts the following values:
>
> - BASIC: Displays the minimum information in the plan—the operation ID, the operation name and its option.
> - TYPICAL: This is the default. Displays the most relevant information in the plan (operation id, name and option, #rows, #bytes and optimizer cost). Pruning, parallel and predicate information are only displayed when applicable. Excludes only PROJECTION, ALIAS, and REMOTE SQL information (see below).
> - SERIAL: Like TYPICAL except that the parallel information is not displayed, even if the plan executes in parallel.
> - ALL: Maximum user level. Includes information displayed with the TYPICAL level with additional information (PROJECTION, ALIAS and information about REMOTE SQL if the operation is distributed).

*In fact, 'ALL' is not a "Maximum level". There is also more detailed format - `advanced`, but it's not documented officially (though you can find it on MOS), so I wouldn't suggest it.*

For example, we have these tables and indexes:

```sql
create table table_1(col1 primary key,col2,col3)
  as select 
        level,
        trunc(level/10) as col2,
        rpad('x',100) as col3
     from dual
     connect by level<=10000;
create table table_2(col1,col2,col3)
  as select 
        level,
        trunc(level/10) as col2,
        rpad('x',100) as col3
     from dual
     connect by level<=10000;
create index BAD_INDEX on table_2(col2,col1);
```

Let's get an execution plan for this query:

```sql
explain plan for
Select
 b.col1,
 b.col2,
 b.col3 
FROM
  (Select
    a.col1,
    a.col2,
    a.col3
  FROM 
   (SELECT
       t.col1,
       t.col2,
       t.col3
    FROM table_1 t
    JOIN table_2 t2
         on t.col1 = t2.col1
    WHERE
        t2.col2=:bind
   ) a
) b;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display('','','all +outline +hint_report'));
```

Execution plan:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2962753836

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |              |    10 |  1170 |    12   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                |              |    10 |  1170 |    12   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS               |              |    10 |  1170 |    12   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | BAD_INDEX    |    10 |    80 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C0010147 |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE_1      |     1 |   109 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$535BA485
   3 - SEL$535BA485 / T2@SEL$3
   4 - SEL$535BA485 / T@SEL$3
   5 - SEL$535BA485 / T@SEL$3

Outline Data
-------------

  /*+
      BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
      NLJ_BATCHING(@"SEL$535BA485" "T"@"SEL$3")
      USE_NL(@"SEL$535BA485" "T"@"SEL$3")
      LEADING(@"SEL$535BA485" "T2"@"SEL$3" "T"@"SEL$3")
      INDEX(@"SEL$535BA485" "T"@"SEL$3" ("TABLE_1"."COL1"))
      INDEX(@"SEL$535BA485" "T2"@"SEL$3" ("TABLE_2"."COL2" "TABLE_2"."COL1"))
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$3")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$4")
      MERGE(@"SEL$3" >"SEL$4")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$37633EB5")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$2")
      MERGE(@"SEL$37633EB5" >"SEL$2")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$BB1798A6")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$1")
      MERGE(@"SEL$BB1798A6" >"SEL$1")
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$535BA485")
      ALL_ROWS
      DB_VERSION('19.1.0')
      OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('19.1.0')
      IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
      END_OUTLINE_DATA
  */

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("T2"."COL2"=TO_NUMBER(:BIND))
   4 - access("T"."COL1"="T2"."COL1")

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------

   1 - (#keys=0) "T"."COL1"[NUMBER,22], "T"."COL2"[NUMBER,22],
       "T"."COL3"[VARCHAR2,100]
   2 - (#keys=0) "T".ROWID[ROWID,10], "T"."COL1"[NUMBER,22]
   3 - "T2"."COL1"[NUMBER,22]
   4 - "T".ROWID[ROWID,10], "T"."COL1"[NUMBER,22]
   5 - "T"."COL2"[NUMBER,22], "T"."COL3"[VARCHAR2,100]
```

As you can see, we have NESTED LOOPS with 2 index access here:
line #3 - IRS (Index Range Scan) by BAD_INDEX, and line #4 IUS (Index Unique Scan).
and in the `OUTLINE` section we see 4 most interesting hints for us:

```
      USE_NL(@"SEL$535BA485" "T"@"SEL$3")
      LEADING(@"SEL$535BA485" "T2"@"SEL$3" "T"@"SEL$3")
      INDEX(@"SEL$535BA485" "T"@"SEL$3" ("TABLE_1"."COL1"))
      INDEX(@"SEL$535BA485" "T2"@"SEL$3" ("TABLE_2"."COL2" "TABLE_2"."COL1"))
```

So for example, if we want to disable index access to T2, we can look at the outline hint
`INDEX(@"SEL$535BA485" "T2"@"SEL$3" ("TABLE_2"."COL2" "TABLE_2"."COL1"))`
take the query block (QBName for short) from it - `@"SEL$535BA485"` and table alias - `"T2"@"SEL$3"` and add use them in our hint as `NO_INDEX(@"SEL$535BA485" "T2"@"SEL$3" BAD_INDEX)`

Example #2:

```sql
explain plan for
Select--+ NO_INDEX(@"SEL$535BA485" "T2"@"SEL$3")
 b.col1,
 b.col2,
 b.col3 
FROM
  (Select
    a.col1,
    a.col2,
    a.col3
  FROM 
   (SELECT
       t.col1,
       t.col2,
       t.col3
    FROM table_1 t
    JOIN table_2 t2
         on t.col1 = t2.col1
    WHERE
        t2.col2=:bind
   ) a
) b;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display('','','all +outline +hint_report'));
```

Execution plan #2:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 247834218

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |              |    10 |  1170 |    58   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                |              |    10 |  1170 |    58   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS               |              |    10 |  1170 |    58   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL         | TABLE_2      |    10 |    80 |    48   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C0010147 |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE_1      |     1 |   109 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$535BA485
   3 - SEL$535BA485 / T2@SEL$3
   4 - SEL$535BA485 / T@SEL$3
   5 - SEL$535BA485 / T@SEL$3

Outline Data
-------------

  /*+
      BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
      NLJ_BATCHING(@"SEL$535BA485" "T"@"SEL$3")
      USE_NL(@"SEL$535BA485" "T"@"SEL$3")
      LEADING(@"SEL$535BA485" "T2"@"SEL$3" "T"@"SEL$3")
      INDEX(@"SEL$535BA485" "T"@"SEL$3" ("TABLE_1"."COL1"))
      FULL(@"SEL$535BA485" "T2"@"SEL$3")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$3")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$4")
      MERGE(@"SEL$3" >"SEL$4")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$37633EB5")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$2")
      MERGE(@"SEL$37633EB5" >"SEL$2")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$BB1798A6")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$1")
      MERGE(@"SEL$BB1798A6" >"SEL$1")
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$535BA485")
      ALL_ROWS
      DB_VERSION('19.1.0')
      OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('19.1.0')
      IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
      END_OUTLINE_DATA
  */

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter("T2"."COL2"=TO_NUMBER(:BIND))
   4 - access("T"."COL1"="T2"."COL1")

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------

   1 - (#keys=0) "T"."COL1"[NUMBER,22], "T"."COL2"[NUMBER,22],
       "T"."COL3"[VARCHAR2,100]
   2 - (#keys=0) "T".ROWID[ROWID,10], "T"."COL1"[NUMBER,22]
   3 - "T2"."COL1"[NUMBER,22]
   4 - "T".ROWID[ROWID,10], "T"."COL1"[NUMBER,22]
   5 - "T"."COL2"[NUMBER,22], "T"."COL3"[VARCHAR2,100]

Hint Report (identified by operation id / Query Block Name / Object Alias):
Total hints for statement: 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

   3 -  SEL$535BA485 / T2@SEL$3
           -  NO_INDEX(@"SEL$535BA485" "T2"@"SEL$3")
```

As you can see, IRS was replaced to FTS (Full Table Scan - `TABLE ACCESS FULL` in the plan) and `hint_report` section shows that our hint was used successfully.

In fact, this example query is too simple and CBO can understand even standard `no_index(b.a.t2)` here (example below), but don't forget that it may not work for more complex ANSI syntax as I mentioned above.

```
explain plan for
Select--+ NO_INDEX(b.a.t2)
 b.col1,
 b.col2,
 b.col3 
FROM
  (Select
    a.col1,
    a.col2,
    a.col3
  FROM 
   (SELECT
       t.col1,
       t.col2,
       t.col3
    FROM table_1 t
    JOIN table_2 t2
         on t.col1 = t2.col1
    WHERE
        t2.col2=:bind
   ) a
) b;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display('','','all +outline +hint_report'));
```

Example #3:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 247834218

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |              |    10 |  1170 |    58   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                |              |    10 |  1170 |    58   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS               |              |    10 |  1170 |    58   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL         | TABLE_2      |    10 |    80 |    48   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C0010147 |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE_1      |     1 |   109 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$535BA485
   3 - SEL$535BA485 / T2@SEL$3
   4 - SEL$535BA485 / T@SEL$3
   5 - SEL$535BA485 / T@SEL$3

Outline Data
-------------

  /*+
      BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
      NLJ_BATCHING(@"SEL$535BA485" "T"@"SEL$3")
      USE_NL(@"SEL$535BA485" "T"@"SEL$3")
      LEADING(@"SEL$535BA485" "T2"@"SEL$3" "T"@"SEL$3")
      INDEX(@"SEL$535BA485" "T"@"SEL$3" ("TABLE_1"."COL1"))
      FULL(@"SEL$535BA485" "T2"@"SEL$3")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$3")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$4")
      MERGE(@"SEL$3" >"SEL$4")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$37633EB5")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$2")
      MERGE(@"SEL$37633EB5" >"SEL$2")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$BB1798A6")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$1")
      MERGE(@"SEL$BB1798A6" >"SEL$1")
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$535BA485")
      ALL_ROWS
      OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_nlj_hj_adaptive_join' 'false')
      OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_strans_adaptive_pruning' 'false')
      OPT_PARAM('_px_adaptive_dist_method' 'off')
      DB_VERSION('19.1.0')
      OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('19.1.0')
      IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
      END_OUTLINE_DATA
  */

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter("T2"."COL2"=TO_NUMBER(:BIND))
   4 - access("T"."COL1"="T2"."COL1")

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------

   1 - (#keys=0) "T"."COL1"[NUMBER,22], "T"."COL2"[NUMBER,22],
       "T"."COL3"[VARCHAR2,100]
   2 - (#keys=0) "T".ROWID[ROWID,10], "T"."COL1"[NUMBER,22]
   3 - "T2"."COL1"[NUMBER,22]
   4 - "T".ROWID[ROWID,10], "T"."COL1"[NUMBER,22]
   5 - "T"."COL2"[NUMBER,22], "T"."COL3"[VARCHAR2,100]

Hint Report (identified by operation id / Query Block Name / Object Alias):
Total hints for statement: 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

   3 -  SEL$535BA485 / T2@SEL$3
           -  NO_INDEX(b.a.t2)
```

Finally, all examples on [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5d4a44a13cb5ca3920794caedeaab44d):
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5d4a44a13cb5ca3920794caedeaab44d